# How do I handle inconsistent accessibility when passing a Generic type object?

Tags: c#, generics

So basically I have this state machine class that accepts generic types

```
namespace BehaviorController.StateMachine
{
    class StateMachine<TStates, TTransitions>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I have this other class that creates an instance of a state machine that can be set by another class in the same namespace

```
using BehaviorController.StateMachine;

namespace Player {
   public enum State { ... }
   public enum Transition { ... }

    public class PlayerController {
        private StateMachine<State, Transition> machine;
        
        public void Setup() {
            // Get instance of sub controller
            ...
            subController.SetStateMachine(machine); // what I'm eventually trying to do
        }
    }

    public class PlayerSubController {
        private StateMachine<State, Transition> machine;
        
        public void SetStateMachine(StateMachine<State, Transition> machine) { // compile error
            this.machine = machine;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason that line keeps getting the error

```
Error   CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'StateMachine<State, Transition>' is less accessible than method 'PlayerSubController.SetStateMachine(StateMachine<State, Transition>)'
```

And I'm confused what this even means. The state machine can be imported and the enums are public to the namespace as well so what's the compiler's issue with this?

Comment: `PlayerSubController` is `public` and `SetStateMachine` is `public`, but `StateMachine` is implicitly `internal`.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it public as well?

Comment: Put `public` in the class declaration: `public class StateMachine<TStates, TTransitions> { ... }`

Comment: I feel super dumb. I thought anything that could import it and create a StateMachine meant it was fully accessible to it. Thanks

Comment: We all have _apply palm to face and say "doh"_ moments

Comment: If you make something public, then external parties who consume your assembly need to be able to call it. Which they can't do if one of the arguments is internal.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple change of making the `StateMachine` class public as well